# tracking / monitoring system

Tags: c, security, shell, ubuntu, monitoring

I have been developing an application which will track the work history of employees in the office.

Hence I need to track the following details of my users Ubuntu users.

- Applications opened.
- Duration for which application was running.
- If the application is like a text editor/video codec like VLC – what files were opened and for what duration.
- Also I want to track the copy/paste history of files/folders on removable media.

Could anyone help me to suggest the header files and functions in C/shell/Perl which would help me to track this?

**Please Note: I am not expecting the keystrokes to be monitored for the sake of privacy.**

It may be that some of these requirements can't be fulfilled, however suggestions on possible features will be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is way too broad, it's not a programming question. Doing this will involve rather high amounts of complexity, unless you can somehow instrument the various applications themselves into doing this work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for 'proc'. The procfs is a filesystem mounted on /proc. Under that directory is a folder for each process by process ID. Of interest to you will be the fd folder for each process. For example, for a process with a PID of 5, the fd folder is

```
/proc/5/fd
```

The fd folder contains a symbolic link for each file handle open by the process. To listen for changes(new processes being launched, new files being opened) on the proc filesystem, I suggest inotify. However, it does have [limitations](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=inotify&page=faq) with respect to procfs.